# UPgrading Win10 OEM

Tags: windows

Moving to a new PC that I'm building myself. Currently running Dell OEM Win10 Home. New PC will have Win10 Pro, MSDN (multi-activation or retail keys) version.

My backup software can do a "system transfer" that will allow me to transfer everything (OS and applications) to the new computer.

Should I upgrade from OEM Home to MSDN Pro on the old computer and then transfer everything to the new computer?

Or just install Win10 PRO MSDN on the new computer and use the backup software vendor's application transfer program to move the applications and registry entries.

My goals are:
    1. Not have any "dinosaur bones" either from the OS on my SSD from the old OEM Home version on the new PRO version
    2. Not have to reinstall and reconfigure everything (which would take about a week)

Thanks for any advice I can get...

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose between the two :

1. Transfer the hard disk as-is with its "dinosaur bones"
2. Do a new install and spend the week installing

I would have preferred personally the second option, as it would give
a more stable setup with just the software you need.

For the first option, I think it is best to transfer the disk as-is.
Windows Home will dis-activate itself, and you may then do an
[in-place upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
to Professional, which is an
[allowed path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-upgrade-paths).
Ensure first that you have installation media for all drivers of devices
not supported by generic Windows.